# Plotting multilayered grouped df with xlim

Tags: python, pandas, plot, multi-level

I have a plot with hourly values for 2019. When plotting with a sub-set of dates (January only) on the x-axis, my plot goes blank.

I have a DF that I group on the row-axis based on Months and Hours from the time index, for a specific column 'SE3'. The grouping looks good.

Now, I want to plot. The plot looks potentially good, but I want to zoom in on one month only. Based on another post on stackoverflow, I use set_xlim.

Then my plot does not show anything.

```
#Grouping of DF
df['SE3'].groupby([df.index.month, df.index.hour]).mean().round(2).head()
```

Picture of grouped DF[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31GDe.png)

```
#Plotting and setting new, shorter in time x-axis
ax=df['SE3'].groupby([df.index.month, df.index.hour]).mean().round(2).plot()
ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 01:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-01-31 23:00:00'))
```

The expected result is to show the same plot, but now only for January. Instead the grap goes blank. However, the Out data shows 
(737060.0416666666, 737090.9583333334), which seems to be date data.

Picture without set_xlim
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uDuu.png)

Picture with set_xlim (empty)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZE5c.png)

My final aim when I understand why my plot is blank, is to show hourly averages for each month, like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnAnp.png)